# Can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I'm trying to set up [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms152536%28v=sql.105%29) and I'm stuck at "Add a New Peer Node" step - I can't connect to another server.

In server name field I specify `serverIP\DBNODE2` and SQL Server credentials.

I'm 100% sure that the credentials are correct, but I'm not sure about the server name part.

[image]

When I try to connect I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I've checked:

- Started SQL Server Browser service
- SQL Server service for MSSQLSERVER is running
- Firewall is off
- Remote connections are enabled in Configuration Manager
- TCP ports are enabled

Server name is `DBNODE2`.
SQL Server instance name is `MSSQLSERVER`.

The only thing, that I don't understand why it's asking `server name`? This server is in remote geographical location, so I don't think, that it could find the right server without IP address.
I've tried bunch of different combinations and none of them worked:

- `IP\DBNODE2`
- `IP\MSSQLSERVER`
- `DBNODE2\MSSQLSERVER`
- `IP`
- `DBNODE2`
- Also tried double backslashes
- Etc.

**EDIT2:**
SQL Server service is running under 1433 port.
I've used Port Query tool, which I've found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified).

```
    =============================================
    Starting portqry.exe -n {IP} -e 1433 -p TCP ...
    IP address resolved to ec2-*******.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): LISTENING
    =============================================
    Starting portqry.exe -n {IP} -e 1434 -p UDP ...
    IP address resolved to ec2-*******.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    UDP port 1434 (ms-sql-m service): LISTENING or FILTERED
    Sending SQL Server query to UDP port 1434...
    Server's response:
    ServerName DBNODE2
    InstanceName MSSQLSERVER
    IsClustered No
    Version 11.0.3000.0
    tcp 1433
    ==== End of SQL Server query response ====
```

**ANSWER:** Probably server IP address is not allowed in `server name` field. The workaround is to modify hosts file like @MarkIannucci decribed below.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64668/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-cant-connect-to-sql-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server's ip address is static, you can modify your `hosts` file with a reference to DBNODE2's ip address and specify DBNODE2 in your `Connect to Server Server Name` file.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that FQDN's aren't allowed in the 'server name' field.  If that is the case, you may be able to have your entry for `DBNODE2` point to the `ec2-********.compute-1.amazonaws.com` in your `hosts` file and get around the static IP address limitation. @Andrew will you give that a shot and report back?

Comment: @MarkIannucci It won't work, because under ****** part hides server IP. For instance if server IP is, let say, `78.80.90.181`, then long version would be like this `ec2-78-80-90-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good practice to use the SQL Server name when configuring the connection. To connect to a SQL server, you need to specify 2 parameters: Server IP address and port. If you only specify the SQL Server name, then you will depend on the naming resolution, it may or may not work as you expect. So the best practice is to use SQL Alias, for more info on how to set up, check out at https://randynghiem.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/best-practices-on-setting-data-connection-for-ssis-packages/